# Does the underlined pronoun '"it" refer to "the first computer program" or "one calculation"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> During that decade, scientists in England developed the first computer program. **It** took 25 minutes to complete one cal

I have arguing with my friends all day long

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Instead OCR or re-type the text. See [*Formatting your posts**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4799/) the section on "Images".

Comment: Now, what is the source of the quoted text, please? Author, title, and a link if possible.

Answer (score 3):

It does not refer to "one calculation".

It could be either "the first computer program", or an expletive subject (with no referent). Either makes sense.